# Which is the still functioning Oldest Watchmaker company on the world?

Tags: industrial-history

Which is the still functioning Oldest Watchmaker company on the world?

Googling gave me three results:

- Blancpain
- JEANRICHARD
- Vacheron Constantin

Comment: What are the criteria for being the "oldest watchmaker"? Date of company establishment? Date of first watch produced? Continuous production? etc. The oldest company making watches may not be the oldest watchmaker.

Comment: Also how do you treat brands that become part of much larger corporations? For example, JeanRichard's history involves the brand changing hands several times becoming part of a larger company each time. Can the modern owner of a brand, in such circumstances, really lay claim to be the oldest watchmaker?

Comment: Could be a random guy who is over 90 years old ;) --edited the question--

Comment: What is wrong with Google's answer?

Comment: Note:. Low rep user; can we take advantage of this opportunity?